# How to make the datagrid cell to accept numbers with comma and n number of decimals

Tags: .net, winforms

I have datagrid in winforms with 4 double type cells.
In design time, I set the Cellformat to "N2".
But its not allowing to enter the value either like 456.23 or 45612,12.23.
If I enter values like above ,tts revert the value  back to previous value.

How to set the cellformat at design time for accepting values like
45,612.52   45,612.5

Edit: Can I do it from code?
All I wants cell should the value in two decimal places like if the cell value is 55,it should show as 55.00.
and user can able to enter the value like 55.12.

Can anyone help on this ASAP.

Comment: I tried it,but cell not allowing to enter value like 78.45 like that.It just accepting values without decimal while entering.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need a custom validator. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ye0dkkw

For validation, you'll want to use [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw). That topic has an example that uses the `AllowThousands` style.

Answer (score 0):

I set the format "#,0.00" at design time.
Now its working.